# Outputting text data from Orange's clustering algorithm

Tags: data-mining, orange

I am interested in using Orange's cluster data mining algorithms to query an inputted data table. I am some what confused though on how to display the relevant textual results from the clustering data query.

From one of the examples in the documentation:

```
import Orange

import random
random.seed(42)

def callback(km):
    print "Iteration: %d, changes: %d, score: %.4f" % (km.iteration,
                                                       km.nchanges,
                                                       km.score)

iris = Orange.data.Table("iris")
km = Orange.clustering.kmeans.Clustering(iris,
                                         3,
                                         minscorechange=0,
                                         inner_callback=callback)
```

Advice on this is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have a look at the `km` object, not the status callback.

Comment: I definitely feel I should have read the manual with glasses on ... print km.data[-10:] ... Thank you Anony-Mousse!

Comment: If Anony-Mousse doesn't want to write an answer, perhaps you could answer your own question and mark it as answered...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As advised by Anony Mousse.

```
import Orange

import random
random.seed(42)

def callback(km):
    #print(km.data[-10:])
    pass

iris = Orange.data.Table("iris")
km = Orange.clustering.kmeans.Clustering(iris,
                                         3,
                                         minscorechange=0,
                                         inner_callback=callback)

print(km.data[-10:])
```